# Is Rails.cache.fetch method atomic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

Specifically, if the key does not exist in the cache, I want to add the key-value pair to the cache. Can this be done atomically using Rails.cache.fetch?

Thanks!

Comment: Which caching option are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You have to write with the `:unless_exist` option:

```
Rails.cache.write(k, v, :unless_exist => true)
```

The method will return true only when the key didn't exist. Otherwise, the method returns false:

```
if Rails.cache.write(k, v, :unless_exist => true)
  # do something only when the key wasn't there
end
```